# Jade engine : set value from variable inside attribute

Tags: javascript, express, pug

I'm beginner in Jade Engine and can't set value inside attribute.
So, I have a similar code:

```
  for job in jobs
   tr
    td
     a(href="/job/= job.ID")= job.Title
```

= job.Title displays correctly, but I can't set job.ID. I need link with href like /job/12345, where 12345 is job.ID.
How to do it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

should be `a(href="/job/#{job.ID}")`

Answer (score 8):

This will work:

```
a(href="/job/" + job.ID)
```